Can't find "docker-compose" tool
I got an Azure custom task which used this line to get the docker compose path and use it to run docker compose:
this.dockerComposePath = tl.which("docker-compose");

It worked until recently, but now it can't find the docker compose tool.. Has something changed recently with this tool or some package related?
I'm not sure if these packages I'm using are related:
"azure-pipelines-task-lib": "3.0.6-preview.0",
"azure-pipelines-tasks-docker-common-v2": "2.0.1-preview.0",


docker-compose has been deprecated. Now it is docker compose. So, the command is docker and compose it's just a parameter. The behavior should be the same.
More info in: Difference between "docker compose" and "docker-compose"

Does it mean that I can switch between tl.which("docker-compose") and tl.which("docker compose") and have the same result as before?

Probably, just check which version of docker is installed in the VM. Also, take into consideration that compose is a parameter, so maybe that will not find in the which command.
